# replace a value in the entire pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
df:

       cat116_O  cat116_S  cat116_T  cat116_U  cat116_Y  
 0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0  
 1       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0  

expected output:

df(changed):

     cat116_O  cat116_S  cat116_T  cat116_U  cat116_Y  
 0      -1       -1        -1         -1        -1
 1      -1       -1        -1         -1        -1

code:

df.replace(0.0, -1)
```

But its not working. I was able to do iteratively for each row and column but it is taking a lot of time. Where am I going wrong with the replace function in the code.

Comment: Why not, `df[df == 0] = -1`?

Comment: @pbreach thanks for the suggestion. I have done that too, my doubt was that why wasnt the replace function working. please suggest me on that.

Comment: Looking [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) it doesn't seem like `DataFrame.replace` is meant for replacing single values. It also seems like it could be pretty slow looking at the source code. What I've mentioned is probably the most direct method.

Comment: Actually, this works fine for me: `pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros((3, 3))).replace(0.0, -1)`.  Do you get an error? Can you give a complete example of demonstrating how it's not working?

Comment: Watch out for floating point arithmetic: if some of your values are not numerically zero, they won't test `True` with `==0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're interested to find out why your replace function is not working.

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
df.replace(to_replace = 0.0, value = -1, inplace = True)
```

This will return `float`(-1.0) values as your your values are floats.